# Pandas Read CSV for file address with \t in it

Tags: python, pandas

This may be a redundant question because I know that I can rename the file and solve the issue, but I'm still pretty new at this and it would be really useful information for the future. Thanks in advance to respondents!

So, I have a CSV file which is a table exported from SQL with the filename "t_SQLtable" located in a sub-folder of my working directory.

In order to open the file in Pandas I use the following command:

```
SQLfile= pd.read_csv('SUBFOLDER\t_SQLtable.csv', sep=',')
```

This is the error I receive:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File SUBFOLDER _SQLtable.csv does not exist: 'SUBFOLDER\t_SQLtable.csv'
```

My understanding is that Pandas is reading the <**\t**> as a tab and thus is not able to find the file, because that's not the file name it is looking for. But I don't know how  to format the text in order to tell Pandas how to recognize the <**t**> as part of the filename. Would anyone know how to resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try adding r before the quotes .. i.e. r'string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders are navigated using `/` which won't escape any character

```
SQLfile= pd.read_csv('SUBFOLDER/t_SQLtable.csv', sep=',')
```

in future if you want to keep `\t` without it being considered as `tab`

use raw string

```
print('SUBFOLDER\t_SQLtable.csv')
print(r'SUBFOLDER\t_SQLtable.csv')
```

```
SUBFOLDER   _SQLtable.csv
SUBFOLDER\t_SQLtable.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Interestingly using ` \ ` seems to work fine when I am opening files that start with letters other than <t>...

Comment: Thanks, I will do so as soon as I'm allowed. Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
SQLfile= pd.read_csv('SUBFOLDER\\t_SQLtable.csv', sep=',')
SQLfile= pd.read_csv('SUBFOLDER/t_SQLtable.csv', sep=',')
```

If doesn't work , then try this:

```
import os

file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "SUBFOLDER", "t_SQLtable.csv")

SQLfile= pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do what you did before, except add an `r` right before the string:

```
SQLfile = pd.read_csv(r'SUBFOLDER\t_SQLtable.csv', sep=',')
```

Adding `r` to the start of a string will make python treat it as a raw string, as in,
 all escape codes won't be evaluated.